# "Unrecognized configuration section exceptionHandling" in WCF service when using Enterprise Library

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, enterprise-library, web-config

I am working on a WCF service and want to use the Enterprise Library ExceptionHandling block to send the fault message back to the client but I am running into a problem.  I have found very little on the web about this error.

I added the exceptionHandling block to the web.config and also a reference to exceptionHandling in the configSections but I still get the error.

I have also referenced the ExceptionHandling.WCF dll in my project.

I shouldn't have to do anything else but it still throws the error when I publish and bring the service up in a browser.

Any ideas?  This is probably something very simple but I just can't find the problem.  Below are the pertinent sections in my web.config:

```
      <section name="exceptionHandling" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Configuration.ExceptionHandlingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />

  <exceptionHandling>
<exceptionPolicies>
  <add name="WCF Exception Shielding">
    <exceptionTypes>
      <add type="System.InvalidOperationException, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" postHandlingAction="ThrowNewException" name="ArgumentNullException">
        <exceptionHandlers>
          <add
            type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.WCF.FaultContractExceptionHandler, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.WCF"
            name="DefaultFaultContract Handler"
            faultContractType="Bursteg.Samples.WCFIntegration.ServiceContracts.ServiceFault, Bursteg.Samples.WCFIntegration.ServiceContracts">
            <mappings>
              <add name="Id" source="{Guid}"/>
              <add name="MessageText" source="{Message}"/>
            </mappings>
          </add>
        </exceptionHandlers>
      </add>
    </exceptionTypes>
  </add>
</exceptionPolicies>
```

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out.  The exceptionHandling reference needs to be a direct child of the configSections.  I had it a couple of nodes up so it was not referenced.  Just thought I would pass on my solution.

Also, as a side not, the only reference I made was to Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.WCF

```
<configSections>
<section name="exceptionHandling" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Configuration.ExceptionHandlingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
</configSections>
```

Answer (score 0):

do you have a closing tag for `<exceptionHandling>` or did you just forget to copy/paste it in your sample?

Comment: I have a closing tag for <exceptionHandling>.  just missed putting it in.  Sorry.